# View Height returns 0, I want to return View height from onGlobalLayout

Tags: android, layout, view

Here is my Code to return Height of view:

```
int height = 0;
public int getViewHeight(final View v) {
        v.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
                new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

                    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
                    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            v.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            v.getViewTreeObserver()
                                    .removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        height = v.getMeasuredHeight();
//
                        Log.v(" height", v.getMeasuredHeight() + "");
                    }
                });

        Log.v(" return height", v.getMeasuredHeight() + "");
        return height;


    }
```

First It return 0. then the height value changes. 
Can anyone let me know how to return height of view when it measured in onGlobalLayout. Return statement not working in overrided method.

OR

Is there any other way to make a static method which return height of view by passing View instance.

Answer (score -1):

```
***try this way* 
i get View Height and Width as per View**

public class Test extends Activity {

private RelativeLayout layout;
private int temp;
ViewTreeObserver vto;
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("savePref",
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    layout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
    temp = set(layout);
    Log.e("temp", "" + sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 0));
}
private int set(final RelativeLayout layout) {
    vto = layout.getViewTreeObserver();
    final Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    vto.addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            layout.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

            temp = layout.getMeasuredHeight();
            editor.putInt("key", temp);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });
    if (sharedPreferences.contains("key")) {
        Log.e("contains", "" + sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 0));
    }
    return sharedPreferences.getInt("key", 0);
}}
```

Comment: i try this way and it's return height and width as per screen size. u get also width with  relativecontainer.getMeasuredWidth() method

Comment: I want to return this height from onGlobalLayout() method to the caller method. just like int height = getViewHeight(view);

Comment: just make method that return int or u can save it in sharedpreferences and get it back when u need.

Comment: In question I made method to return the height. But this will not work because method return height (which is 0) before the onGlobalLayout() call.