# Android ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener troubles

Tags: android, view

I'm using `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` in `onCreate()` method to get layout's width. It works great, but when I'm manipulating with variables in `onGlobalLayout()` callback changes doesn't kept outside it.

For example, when I'm saving Layout's width in Activity's field it returns previous value or value by default (0 in my case) outside the `onGlobalLayout()` method. When I change variable's referenses they will be null outside the method.

```
layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
@Override
public void onGlobalLayout() {
    width = layout.getWidth(); // width - activity's field
    Log.d("myLogs", width); //return rigth value
}
});
Log.d("myLogs", width); //return 0
```

I have no idea how to deal with it, perhaps I need obtain width of `Layout` in another way.

Thanks in advance)

Comment: **view this url may this help you**

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30886313/view-height-returns-0-i-want-to-return-view-height-from-ongloballayout/30888462#30888462

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You pass `OnGlobalLayoutListener` on for `ViewTreeObserver`, and thats all, method `onGlobalLayout` does not called immediately, it will be called with layout event occurred for this layout. Thus, method `addOnGlobalLayoutListener` immediately and you receive not changed `width` variable value.

Comment: you have no tousle to fix, it is expected behavior. If you need to use correct  width just use it inside `onGlobalLayout` function of `ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener` you have implemented

Comment: and what if I need add views to Layout in this case? I mean if I don't know when `onGlobalLayout()` starts?

Comment: There is no workaround, you can try to get measured width instead, width returns you bottom minus top value, but layout has not drawer yet, so you cann't get it. You can add views in call back of your listener.

Comment: currently reading about meashured width, perhaps it will help me, btw thank you for answer

Answer (score 0):

@busylee says right.

Then if you want to access this value outside ViewTreeObserver the solution is this:

```
private int width;

layout.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
    @Override
    public void onGlobalLayout() {
        int w = layout.getWidth(); // width - activity's field
        Log.d("myLogs", w); //return rigth value
        setWidth(w);
    }
});

private void setWidth(int w) {
    this.width = w;  //get rigth value
    Log.d("myLogs", width);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_account);

    topOfScreen = findViewById(R.id.spc_account_top);
    icon = findViewById(R.id.img_account_icon);

    //[...]


    getPosition();
}

void getPosition(){
    topOfScreen.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            int[] pos = new int[2];
            topOfScreen.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
            topOfScreen.getLocationOnScreen(pos);
            setAnimation(-1*pos[0]);
            Log.d("X and Y Point", pos[0] + " "+ pos[1]);
        }
    });
}

public void setAnimation(int y) {
    icon.animate().translationYBy(y).setDuration(1500);
    screen.animate().setDuration(2000).alpha(1);
}
```

Comment: it did work for me 
Obs.: My annimation is different than yours so edit it

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code dumps without any explanation are rarely helpful. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your question and explain how it works better than what the OP provided.